# Call c# function from Views .cshtml JS code ASP NETCore

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

Really don't uderstand how to call c# function from Views.cshtml JS code

I use ASP.NETCore and created file **IndexController.cs** and **List.cshtml** with simple svg onclick JS funtion test()

**List.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="100" height="100">
        <rect id="12332" fill="#080" width="100" height="100" />
    </svg>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const rect = document.querySelector("rect");
    rect.addEventListener("click", (event) => test(event.target.id))

    function test(id) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Test")?svgId=' + id;

        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => console.log(data));
    }
</script>
```

**IndexController.cs**

```
public class IndexController : Controller
{ 
    [HttpGet]
    public static void Test()
    {
        return;
    }

    public ViewResult List()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I want to call my C# function Test() when I call onclick JS function test()

What I must do? Which services I must connected to my project? Where I must create c# func? How to call this fun?

Now I only have controller .cs and MVC connected to my project as service

---

But my main aim is to pass svg id attribute to c# function when onclick happened, maybe there is better ways how to do it?

### Update 1

Add Url.Action, but still doesn't enter the Test function

Comment: Simply use ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can use evaluated [Url.Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action) in javascript and call specific action in controller

**Example**

```js
const rect = document.querySelector("rect");

function test() {
   const id = rect.id;
   var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Test")?svgId=' + id;

   fetch(url)
     .then(response => response.text())
     .then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

> But my main aim is to pass svg id attribute to c# function when
>   onclick happened, maybe there is better ways how to do it?

Then `addEventListener` would be much better than `onclick` attribute as you can pass `test` function wrapped in a function which gets id from element

```js
const rect = document.querySelector("rect");
rect.addEventListener("click", (event) => test(event.target.id))

function test(id) {
   var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Test")?svgId=' + id;

   fetch(url)
     .then(response => response.text())
     .then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

Comment: Tell me please which function I must add to my controller.cs? public static void GetTest()? public static void Test()? Should I add something like [Url.Action] before Test fun?

Comment: `public static void Test()` add also HttpGet attr

Comment: Pls check my code update.
Chrome debugger wrote "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" on "fetch(url)" function.
Maybe some worth service connecting in my project?